# python amqp 1.3.3 library heartbeat example for rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to detect consumer's connection loss with rabbitmq server using heartbeats.
Can someone please provide me the heartbeat example for python amqp 1.3.3 library.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Look at Celery. It has heartbeat implementation: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/292645c85d0f738407d5914bc17cfa420732a3b9/celery/worker/heartbeat.py